# why pandas create DataFrame in the order of sorted key? I did not do the sort

Tags: python, pandas

code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':[0,20,40,60],'Pressure':[0.0002,0.0012,0.0060,0.0300]})
print(data)
```

outcome:

```
   Pressure  Temp
0    0.0002     0
1    0.0012    20
2    0.0060    40
3    0.0300    60
```

However, I want this:

```
   Temp  Pressure
0   0    0.0002 
1  20    0.0012   
2  40    0.0060   
3  60    0.0300
```

Why the order is not as I specified!

Version of pandas:
pandas:0.22.0

Comment: It's not `pandas`, it's `dict`. `dict` does not keep the insertion order unless you use python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: check with OrderedDict ~

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using `python3.5` or lower, so dictionaries don't maintain insertion order, in your case use an OrderedDict like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict({'Temp':[0,20,40,60],'Pressure':[0.0002,0.0012,0.0060,0.0300]}))
print(data)

>>>
   Temp  Pressure
0     0    0.0002
1    20    0.0012
2    40    0.0060
3    60    0.0300
```